# XSLT for a sequence / position number

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a SAP SHPMNT IDOC where I want an xslt to set sequence numbers if there are N different PARTNER_ID's (customers) in the same STOP element (where PARTNER_Q ='WE').

Most of the time all PARTNER_ID's in a stop are the same but for instance in the next xml I have a  PARTNER_ID 0000015336 and 0000014000 in the same STOP.

In that case I should want the value of the first SEQ element, belonging to PARTNER_ID 0000015336 to be 0 and the next one, belonging to PARTNER_ID 0000014000 to be 1.
If there are more than 1, sequence will be 2,3,etc.

**INPUT XML**

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1EDT20>
            <TKNUM>0000313334</TKNUM>
            <STOP>
                <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                <CMR>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0082227042</VBELN>
                        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                        <SEQ></SEQ>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                    </E1EDL20>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0082227319</VBELN>
                        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                        <SEQ></SEQ>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        </E1EDL20>
                    </CMR>
                </STOP>
                <STOP>
                    <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                    <CMR>
                        <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                            <VBELN>0082227052</VBELN>
                            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                            <SEQ></SEQ>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000004136</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                        </E1EDL20>
                        <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                            <VBELN>0082227329</VBELN>
                            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                            <SEQ></SEQ>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000007136</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000014000</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            </E1EDL20>
                        </CMR>
                    </STOP>
                </E1EDT20>
            </IDOC>
        </SHPMNT05>
```

Current XSLT (since I didn't really know what to do it's worthless)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  <xsl:key name="partnerGroup" match="E1EDL20[E1ADRM1/PARTNER_Q = 'WE']" use="E1ADRM1/PARTNER_ID"/>
  
  <!-- Apply grouping and set SEQ value -->
  <xsl:template match="E1EDL20[SEQ]">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('partnerGroup', 1)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**REQUIRED RESULT**

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1EDT20>
            <TKNUM>0000313334</TKNUM>
            <STOP>
                <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                <CMR>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0082227042</VBELN>
                        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                        <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                    </E1EDL20>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0082227319</VBELN>
                        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                        <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                            <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                        </E1ADRM1>
                        </E1EDL20>
                    </CMR>
                </STOP>
                <STOP>
                    <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
                    <CMR>
                        <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                            <VBELN>0082227052</VBELN>
                            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000004136</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                        </E1EDL20>
                        <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                            <VBELN>0082227329</VBELN>
                            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                            <SEQ>1</SEQ>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000007136</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                                <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                                <PARTNER_ID>0000014000</PARTNER_ID>
                            </E1ADRM1>
                            </E1EDL20>
                        </CMR>
                    </STOP>
                </E1EDT20>
            </IDOC>
        </SHPMNT05>
```

XSLT fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbK7

Sorry for the gibberish / lack of structure in my question. Hope you can follow me :)

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I think the identity transformation plus

```
  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20/STOP[count(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']) = count(distinct-values(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID))]/CMR/E1EDL20/ABLAD">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <SEQ><xsl:number start-at="0" count="E1EDL20"/></SEQ>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20/STOP[count(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']) = count(distinct-values(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID))]/CMR/E1EDL20/SEQ"/>
```

would give a result like

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20>
         <TKNUM>0000313334</TKNUM>
         <STOP>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <CMR>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0082227042</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <SEQ/>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
               </E1EDL20>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0082227319</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <SEQ/>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000006136</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
               </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
         </STOP>
         <STOP>
            <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            <CMR>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0082227052</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <SEQ>0</SEQ>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000004136</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000015336</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
               </E1EDL20>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0082227329</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <SEQ>1</SEQ>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000007136</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
                  <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                     <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                     <PARTNER_ID>0000014000</PARTNER_ID>
                  </E1ADRM1>
               </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
         </STOP>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Note that your posted, wanted result seems to add SEQ numbers in both STOP elements although in the first the PARTNER_IDs seem the same so that somehow contradicts your verbal explanation, at least as far as I have understood it.

I also would need to check whether `xsl:number start-at` is supported in XSLT 2 as well as XSLT 3. According to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-number `start-at` is not supported in XSLT 2, so the code

```
<SEQ><xsl:number start-at="0" count="E1EDL20"/></SEQ>
```

would need to be changed to

```
<SEQ><xsl:variable name="no" as="xs:integer"><xsl:number count="E1EDL20"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="$no - 1"/></SEQ>
```

if you are really using an XSLT 2 processor (all supported versions of e.g. Saxon are XSLT 3 processors and should support start-at).

As for your comment, I still don't have a clear idea as to when/where you want to add a SEQ but in the end it is all doable in that predicate and perhaps in the `xsl:number` so e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20/STOP[count(distinct-values(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID)) gt 1]/CMR/E1EDL20/ABLAD">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:variable name="partner_id" select="../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID"/>
    <SEQ>
      <xsl:number start-at="0" count="E1EDL20[E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID = $partner_id]"/>
    </SEQ>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="E1EDT20/STOP[count(distinct-values(CMR/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q = 'WE']/PARTNER_ID)) gt 1]/CMR/E1EDL20/SEQ"/>
```

tries to give the same SEQ to E1EDL20 with the same PARTNER_ID.

Perhaps you can adjust the condition to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin! Sorry for not being specific enought. I want a default value of 0 but I can fix that in the mapping. I there are 1 or more deliveries (E1EDL20's) with a different PARTNER_ID I want every different one to be SEQ += 1. That said, there can be more than 1 E1EDL20 (delivery) in a stop for a PARTNER_ID. Your XSLT works fine with one E1EDL20 → https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbK7/1
But when I add an extra E1EDL20 (with the same PARTNER_ID) I get   <SEQ/>
→ https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbK7/2

Comment: @MikeDole, I have edited the answer with some adaption, perhaps that helps. Still have no clear understanding as to what are the criteria to add SEQ and where.

Comment: Thanks again Martin. As for your remark: 'As for your comment, I still don't have a clear idea as to when/where you want to add a SEQ' → On the level of STOP (so mulitple E1EDL20) if all have the same PARTNER_ID where PARTNER_Q = WE then this can be empty / 0 but if one or more of the PARTNER_ID's different I want the SEQ to be 1 (next different PARTNER_ID = 2, next one = 3, etc).